# Creating a report of Completed hours for an sprint for each Developer on the basis of

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-reports

We are using TFS2015 in our organisation. Each developer has to fill in time-sheet every month according to the work-packages they are working on.

So we decided to Tag each of the Task/bugs with the concerned Work package in TFS.

To provide developers an idea of how much they have worked on individual work package. We want to provide them with the completed hours under each work package.

We want a matrix showing Developers vs Tags, with values showing the sum of completed hours, of those tasks which have the same tag and belong to that developer. This value will be calculated for each sprint. The report can look something like this:

```
       Tag1   Tag2   Tag3   Tag4
Dev1   20      0      10     6
Dev2    0     12       0     4
Dev3   13      7       0     0
```

We have a daily  burn-down report which shows each user's remaining & completed hours, but distribution like above on the Tags (Work packages) would help them to know approx how many hours to fill in there time sheet after the end of the sprint.

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in report can be generated to get what you want. The only way is to create your own reporting project and create your own data sources.